# How to create a context that you can access?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

Is it possible to create a context that is accessible from a set of windows but not from a different set?

For example, two web request are running in their own context and objects like `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` are pointing to different instances.

My application is a Word like application with a `PlanWindow` that open a plan document. I would like to be able to do something like `PlanContext.Current` which would return me the current plan, instead of having to pass the document around to any dialog that is opened from this `PlanWindow`.

I presume that this has something to do with threading but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Passing the ParentForm reference to the ChildForm is not an unreasonalbe thing to do. You could then check any public properties on the ParentForm that you wanted.

Comment: Where do you want to call the "PlanContext.Current" ? Is it only in your GUI objects (UserControls and Forms) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tackled a similar problem in one of my projects. I used the [GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.getdata.aspx) and [SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.setdata.aspx) methods of **[System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx).**

The CallContext is unique to each thread and you can use it to store objects that are specific to the thread.

In this particular scenario, I would create a PlanContext class like this:

```
public class PlanContext
{
    const string _PlanDocumentSessionKey = "Current_PlanDocument";
    public static PlanDocument Current
    {
        get
        {
            return CallContext.GetData(_PlanDocumentSessionKey) as PlanDocument;
        }
        set
        {
            CallContext.SetData(_PlanDocumentSessionKey,value);
        }
    }
}
```

And in code where you instantiate the document, add this:

```
PlanContext.Current = newDocument;
```

FYI, HttpContext.Current also uses CallContext to retrieve the Context for a particular thread.

Comment: In the Winform context, you have 1 single GUI thread. Using CallContext would always return the same PlanDocument ... So this would be equivalent to a static property named Current on the PlanContext class. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: If he is planning to use a single thread, a static variable will do just fine. But I assumed he wants to use multiple threads for each of the PlanWindow he creates (since he was comparing his scenario to two webrequests). 

Personally,  I feel using multiple threads is a better approach since a modal dialog (say print dialog) opened in one of the windows will not block the input for another document.

Answer (score 1):

How about solving this with the following architecture:

```
IPlanContextReceiver
{   
     public object StateByWichPlanContextCanDeciceWhatToReturn get;
}

class SomeWindow : Window, IPlanContextReceiver
```

And in PlanContext, instead the Current property you have

```
public static PlanContext GetCurrent(IPlanContextReceiver receiver)
{
     lock(contextSync) // be threadsafe if necessary
     {
         if(/*condition that checks receiver.StateByWichPlanContextCanDeciceWhatToReturn*/)
         {
            // context is valid for this receiver
            // return the correct context from an internal store or similar
            return Contexts["TheContextForCoolReceivers"];
         }
         else if(/*condition that checks receiver.StateByWichPlanContextCanDeciceWhatToReturn*/)
         {
            // context is valid for this receiver
            // return the correct context from an internal store or similar
            return Contexts["TheContextForUncoolReceivers"];
         }

         // no existing context is available for this receiver
         return null;
    } 
}
```

If you make it a singleton again `GetCurrent` could also be an instance method. And instead of a Method it could also be a indexer - that is a matter of taste.

Also, it is up to you what `StateByWichPlanContextCanDeciceWhatToReturn` actually is. It could be as complex as multiple properties that need to be checked or it could be as simple as a string that you set once for each f your window context groups.

Answer (score 1):

So here is another proposition wich work even if the active form is a dialog box :

**1) Flag all your Window (child windows) with this interface :**

```
public interface IPlanViewer
{
    //this means that all you windows will have this property
    PlanDocument Document { get; }
}
```

**2) Create the "Context" class**

```
public class Context
{
    public static Context Current { get; set; }
    public IPlanDocument Document { get; set; }
    static Context()
    {
        Current = new Context();
    }
}
```

**3) In you MDI form handle the MdiChildActive event with this method**

```
private void MdiForm_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentView = Form.ActiveForm as IPlanViewer;
    if (currentView != null)
        Context.Current.Document = currentView.Document;
}
```

**4) Use this context like this**

```
private void WorkWithCurrentDoc() 
{
    var doc = Context.Current.Document;
    doc.Title = "totot"
    // etc ...
}
```

That's it. Is it any better ?

Manitra.

Answer (score 0):

A static dictionary?  PlanContext[sessionID] ?

Comment: But that would force me to carry a SessionId around. If I am to pass a value to all form and object, it must as well be the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, so I can only point you in a direction that seems correct.

First, here's how to use Application.Run on two threads to make to multiple "main" windows in a Windows Forms Application, each on their own thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx

Secondly, here's how to have per-thread state:

[How does HttpContext.Current work in a multi-threaded environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561036/how-does-httpcontext-current-work-in-a-multi-threaded-environment/1561059#1561059)

http://blogs.msdn.com/jfoscoding/archive/2006/07/18/670497.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that this has nothing to do with threading.

If by `Current`, you mean `Selected or Active Plan`, then you can set a `Property` on the `PlanWindow` object that tracks the selected Plan (i.e: updated whenever a different plan is selected/activated) and have this property be accessible to all other windows/dialogs (make it static for example)

Answer (score 0):

First, i'll assume that you're application is a MDI Windows Form one and each child windows displays a document to the user.

**1) Flag all your Window (child windows) with this interface :**

```
public interface IPlanViewer
{
    //this means that all you windows will have this property
    PlanDocument Document { get; }
}
```

**2) Create the "Context" class**

```
public class Context
{
    public static Context Current { get; set; }
    static Context()
    {
        Current = new Context();
    }

    //The key method : I'm returning the document of the currently selected child windows or null if no windows are opened
    public PlanDocument Document
    {
        get { 
            var currentView =  Form.ActiveForm as IPlanViewer;
            if (currentView != null)
                return currentView.Document;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**3) Use this context like this**

```
private void WorkWithCurrentDoc() 
{
    var doc = Context.Current.Document;
    doc.Title = "totot"
    // etc ...
}
```

That's it. I hope this will help you.

Manitra.

Comment: The problem I have with using Form.ActiveForm is that if I am in a Dialog, this is now the active form and not the IPlanViewer.

Comment: Hi Pierre Alain, I understand your problem, I just submited another answere that could be better.