# Need to auto refresh Asp.Net page as per Server time on a regular interval.... like 7:06 AM,8:06 AM,9:06 AM,10:06 AM, 11:06 AM......till 9:06 PM

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse, page-refresh, response.redirect

Code is  like given below, i am using Timer's event handler "ElapsedEventHandler" to call Response.AppendHeader or Response.Redirect methods, but i am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the Response object. Anyone who can help on this ??

**Want to set the refresh time dynamically then that can be done in ASP.NET by adding server side code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    const double interval60Minutes = 60 * 60 * 1000; // milliseconds to one hour

    Timer checkForTime = new Timer(interval60Minutes);

    //checkForTime.
    checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
    checkForTime.Enabled = true;
  }
}

public void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (timeIsReady(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt").ToLower())) //12 Hour Date Format : 03:01 PM
  {
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "2;Slider.aspx");

    //Or
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Slider.aspx");
  }
}

private bool timeIsReady(string time)
{
  if (time.Contains("07:06 am"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("08:06 am"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("09:06 am"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("10:06 am"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("11:06 am"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("00:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("01:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("02:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("03:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("04:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("05:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("06:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("07:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("08:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else if (time.Contains("09:06 pm"))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of timer causes HttpContext.Current to be null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652038/use-of-timer-causes-httpcontext-current-to-be-null)

Comment: There is no response when the timer fires.

Comment: @CodeCaster any clue, how can we achieve this ???

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used the Timer control but in general feel that the `Ajax Extensions` and `UpdatePanels` are broken, outdated and should be avoided. This is an approach we took years ago. It defines a custom control that you need to add to your page. (You can't just instantiate it.)

You will need to modify the `seconds` value and register the control etc. I have no idea if this control will work within an `UpdatePanel` but I doubt it.

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:PostBackTimer runat=\"server\" />"), DefaultProperty("Seconds"), DefaultEvent("Timeout")]
public class PostBackTimer : Control, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    public PostBackTimer() { }

    [Description("PostBackTimer_OnTimeout")]
    public event EventHandler Timeout = delegate { };

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        Timeout(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        var seconds = 45;

        var postback = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, null);
        var script = string.Format("setTimeout(\"{0}\",{1});", postback, seconds * 1000);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "PostBackTimer_" + UniqueID, script, true);

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```